# How to change index image to background image in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, color-conversion, color-indexing

I have recently opened some images and in the layers palette, instead of saying "background" it says "Index".

I have been unable to figure out why it says "index" and cannot do anything to the image because every tool is greyed out. What's up? I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Select `Image > Mode > RGB color`

Comment: Thank you! Just curious - why does this happen in the first place? I am three weeks into learning the program, all relevant info is great. Thank you!

Comment: This does not just happen. Someone indexed the image, possibly to reduce file size or use a specific color set.

Comment: Although I don't know why, Photoshop shows .bmp files as 'indexed'. This may happen when you directly drag the image from your browser in to PS, and PS makes a .bmp file out of it (on Windows at least). The easiest thing to do is to first download the file, or just copy the indexed layer and paste it into a new file so that it's editable.

Comment: You know they you are commenting on an accepted answer? There is no reason for speculation. What information are you trying to add?

Comment: The solution was provided indeed, but I think this is some useful additional information that explains it a little bit more.

Comment: As I said, what are you explaining exactly?

Answer (score 1):

open the index with windows paint and save it as jpg. Then , you can edit it on photoshop as background and process that. I hope that this will help you!